# Visa needed or not for a transfer between Paris airports?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, paris

My friend is an Indian citizen and will be travelling to London for a business trip. The visa is valid till the date of his return flight. His return flight has a stop over in Paris for more than 12 hours. His flight from London stops at ORY (Orly) and leaves to India from CDG (Charles de Gaulle).

Does my friend need a visa for France?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, a visa will be required, as your friend will need to leave the ORY airport and travel to CDG "landside" through France.

This case is explicitly listed as one in which a visa is required at the bottom of the following page:
[France Diplomatie](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/what-type-of-visa-do-i-need-to)